# Gradle plugin for JsonSchema validator

Tags: validation, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am writing [jsonSchema](http://json-schema.org/) for my model classes which will be used to generate classes in different languages. I am currently using gradle to publish schema file to an artifactory. I want to basically validate the schema before publishing it to artifactory. I checked online but couldn't find proper gradle plugin. There are plugins which are validating the json files against the schema file (which is not exactly my requirement)

Is there a way to validate the jsonSchema file? If there is a java library which does this than that is also fine with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by @Pedro [json-schema-validator](https://github.com/daveclayton/json-schema-validator) does validate the schema files but it does not allow directory which can contains multiple files.

I filed an [issue](https://github.com/daveclayton/json-schema-validator/issues/216) against that project and also send a [pull request](https://github.com/daveclayton/json-schema-validator/pull/218). Hopefully it will be merged to the main branch and will be available for others.

It provides the command line tool which does the schema validation. I stumble upon [gradle-json-validator](https://github.com/alenkacz/gradle-json-validator) which does provide schema validation. I am going to use this instead.

Answer (score 0):

This one:
https://github.com/daveclayton/json-schema-validator

Not sure if it's your case but you could also try validating some json samples that you know beforehand are valid or invalid against your json schema and check that the result is correct.

Also:
http://json-schema.org/implementations#validator-java

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for sharing link. I have already looked into json-schema-validator it basically validate the json file against the jsonschema but it doesn't validate the jsonschema itself.